# Cannot find page in API

Tags: python, wagtail

I'm following the online tutorials of wagtail 2, and am interested in the API so I did not do all the templates. [general tutorial](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.1.1/getting_started/tutorial.html) [api tutorial](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.1.1/advanced_topics/api/v2/configuration.html)

After I created blogs in the admin panel I cannot access them with the API at `http://example.com/api/v2/pages/`: I only find the home page in the response. Do you need templates in order to find them in the API?

Comment: No you shouldn't need a template, I wouldn't think. Although I have templates in my wagtail sites to serve frontend pages and to get API responses. Have you made sure your page has `api_fields = Page.api_fields + [ APIField("twitter_url"), ..... ]`?

Comment: No I used `api_fields = [APIField('date'), APIField('intro'), APIField('body')]` as described in http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.1.1/advanced_topics/api/v2/configuration.html. So without the Page.api_fields.

Comment: The API also doesn't complain the type doesn't exist, it merely confirms `"total_count": 0` (whereas the admin panel does show them)

Comment: What happens when you go to http://localhost:8000/api/v2/pages/4/?fields=* (change /4/ for your pageId that you're testing).

Comment: @KalobTaulien: Get `"message": "No Page matches the given query."`, if take the page id from the admin 'edit' URL (7 in this case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you created your Blog index page at the Root level then you will have to assign a Site to it.

> Settings > Sites -> Add Site

The default one is set to localhost and has the HomePage assigned to it.

Afterwards, the blog pages created will be accessible as Pages via the API.